# Error PostgreSQL CENTOS restart server, Failed to start PostgreSQL 9.6 database server

Tags: centos, postgresql

Failed to start PostgreSQL 9.6 database server.

I restarted my database server on CENTOS and now PostgreSQL doesn't wake up the service, journalctl -xe says:

### -- The result is failed.
Nov 06 10:17:21 pgbdtest.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit postgresql-9.6.service entered failed state.
Nov 06 10:17:21 pgbdtest.localdomain systemd[1]: postgresql-9.6.service failed.
Nov 06 10:17:21 pgbdtest.localdomain polkitd[8967]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:10570:80525 (system bus name :1.50, object path /org/fr
Nov 06 10:17:44 pgbdtest.localdomain polkitd[8967]: Registered Authentication Agent for unix-process:10614:83776 (system bus name :1.53 [/usr/bin/pkttyagent -
Nov 06 10:17:48 pgbdtest.localdomain polkitd[8967]: Operator of unix-process:10614:83776 successfully authenticated as unix-user:dhurtado to gain ONE-SHOT aut
Nov 06 10:17:48 pgbdtest.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL 9.6 database server...
-- Subject: Unit postgresql-9.6.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel

### -- Unit postgresql-9.6.service has begun starting up.
Nov 06 10:17:48 pgbdtest.localdomain postgresql96-check-db-dir[10630]: "/var/lib/pgsql/9.6/data/" is missing or empty.
Nov 06 10:17:48 pgbdtest.localdomain postgresql96-check-db-dir[10630]: Use "/usr/pgsql-9.6/bin/postgresql96-setup initdb" to initialize the database cluster.
Nov 06 10:17:48 pgbdtest.localdomain postgresql96-check-db-dir[10630]: See /usr/share/doc/postgresql96-9.6.13/README.rpm-dist for more information.
Nov 06 10:17:48 pgbdtest.localdomain systemd[1]: postgresql-9.6.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Nov 06 10:17:48 pgbdtest.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start PostgreSQL 9.6 database server.
-- Subject: Unit postgresql-9.6.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel

### -- Unit postgresql-9.6.service has failed.

### -- The result is failed.
Nov 06 10:17:48 pgbdtest.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit postgresql-9.6.service entered failed state.
Nov 06 10:17:48 pgbdtest.localdomain systemd[1]: postgresql-9.6.service failed.
Nov 06 10:17:48 pgbdtest.localdomain polkitd[8967]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:10614:83776 (system bus name :1.53, object path /org/fr
Nov 06 10:18:47 pgbdtest.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting Cleanup of Temporary Directories...
-- Subject: Unit systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel

### -- Unit systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service has begun starting up.
Nov 06 10:18:47 pgbdtest.localdomain systemd[1]: Started Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
-- Subject: Unit systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel

### -- Unit systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service has finished starting up.

-- The start-up result is done.

Comment: `"/var/lib/pgsql/9.6/data/" is missing or empty.` Did you confirm this?